# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() python numpy using ReLu function

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, relu

```
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork():

    def __init__(self):
        np.random.seed(1)

        self.synaptic_weights = np.random.random((8, 5))

    def rectified(self, x):

        return max(0, x)

    def rectified_derivative(x):
         x[x<=0] = 0
         x[x>0] = 1
         return x

    def train(self, training_inputs, training_outputs, training_iterations):

        for iteration in range(training_iterations):
            output = self.think(training_inputs)

            error = training_outputs - output

            adjustments = np.dot(training_inputs.T, error * self.rectified_derivative(output))

            self.synaptic_weights += adjustments

    def think(self, inputs):

        inputs = inputs.astype(float)
        output = self.rectified(np.dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))
        return output
```

Not sure why i am receiving this error. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Error is on this line:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
    return max(0, x)
```

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: You are trying to find the maximum of `0` and an array `x`, which is ambigious, since there are multiple values in `x`. 

You can do:
`return [max(0, xval) for xval in x]
`

instead of 
`return max(0, x)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to clamp all the values to be non-negative, use [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) as follows:

```
x.clip(0)
```

Python's builtin `max` operator does not play well with numpy arrays